# SQL Execution - Unable to parse query text

Tags: sql, master-data-services, mds

I'm trying to do a bulk load from a CSV into MDS (via SSIS package) but I keep getting this error:

> Unable to parse query text.

Any ideas what's causing this? Screenshot is below:

[image]

This is all within Visual Studios. The actual package runs but when I get to the Integration Manager, I don't see anything there:

Flow:

[image]

MDS Integration Manager (after "successfully" running package)

[image]

Comment: what happens when you add exec in sql statement

Comment: So I originally had "EXEC" in the query but it gave me a different error saying "The EXEC SQL construct or statement is not supported".